# How to plot data with datetimes and nan objects?

Tags: python, datetime, plot, nan

I want to plot a function vs time, but there are some gaps that I need to be included. My data looks something like this:

```
function = [0, 5, 19, 10, nan, nan, 10, 15]
times = [10, 11, 12, 13, nan, nan, 16, 17]
```

I need the plot to show the gap between 13-16. Right now, when I try to plot it gives me an error...

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I believe its being caused by the nans within the dates list. How could I fix this?

Comment: i think pandas.interpolate will fill your x axis ... and i think nan is fine for the y axis

Comment: What do you want the gap to be replaced by ? If you do not know maybee just supress the Nan, and use a matplotlib.pyplot.plot so the figure is drawn with what you have.

Comment: user numpy.nan for the nan values and it should be handled properly

Answer (score 0):

With numpy ou can replace nan by np.nan which is properly handled by matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

function = [0, 5, 19, 10, np.nan,np.nan, 10, 15]
times = [10, 11, 12, 13, np.nan,np.nan,16, 17]
plt.plot(times, function)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can also replace nan by None if you do not want to use numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pandas without numpy as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"times":[10, 11, 12, 13, None, None, 16, 17], "function" :[0, 5, 19, 10, None, None, 10, 15]})
print(df)

plt.plot(df.times, df.function)
plt.xlabel('times')
plt.ylabel('function')
plt.show()

#Here is the df with NaN values:
   times  function
0   10.0       0.0
1   11.0       5.0
2   12.0      19.0
3   13.0      10.0
4    NaN       NaN
5    NaN       NaN
6   16.0      10.0
7   17.0      15.0
```

[image]